# Getting the right URL of Google Place photo with angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I use angular 5 to retrieve photo URL from Google Place, like this :

```
...
var request = {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(this.mylat,this.mylng),
  radius: 100,
  type: this.searchtype
};
let places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.mymap);
places.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    results.forEach((place, index) => {
     var img_url = place.photos[0].getUrl({"maxWidth": 200, "maxHeight": 200}); // This URL works only for a few days..
    });
  }
})
...
```

This URL is stored in my Firestore DB to be used later.

Problem :
Google maps gives a temporary URL (valid only for a few days).
This URL redirects to a 'real' (permanent) URL.

Exemple :

Temporary URL : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?1sCmRaAAAAw_I6Al73qDad8ouQIOKMh38e_CRFB3bWj3hh7hBGeJB6YoWfeBfmDQkptvjuoval_kHABgM_yiJlDpmVF7XnMBu0LbhGbekdRCdezWbj4K2_h5scVqs_-peixhu-E83DEhBTeZpeIgJsAmzzbCyPdZg9GhRls6eH4OzIalD2Xy5CuIKrOxbduw&3u200&4u200&5m1&2e1&key=MYKEY&callback=none&token=26668

Real/permanent (redirect to) URL : https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO4Xz37yaVeLaLL8ndNQKR93b5qvClsSis11koi=s1600-w200-h200

How can I get this real URL and not the temporary one ?

Answer (score -1):

Without using a hacky solution, I don't think the `googleusercontent` URL is retrievable.

If what you need is a permanent URL for the image, I suggest using Google's Places [web API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) to retrieves the images reference, and that reference could be used anytime to fetch the image.